# Stop the keyboard from suggesting words from all downloaded languages

Tags: samsung, keyboard, languages, dictionary

I recently installed 4 languages on Samsung Galaxy S10+. To my surprise, regardless of the language I choose to write in (= scroll to), it seems to suggest words in *all 4 of them* simultaneously.

[image: With Português (BR) selected, typing "merit" suggests "merit", "merkt", and "mérite" on the keyboard]

It seems like the system has got all 4 mixed up or together.

Any ideas on why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify that you're using the native Samsung keyboard, but it looks as though you are from the screenshot. If you go into the keyboard settings, under "More typing options," there should be a setting for "Multilanguage text prediction," which you can disable.